# Different styles.xml for different api's

Tags: android, android-styles

I have the following `styles.xml` in my app to laod a progressspinner:

```
<style name="MyProgressBarSpinner" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progressspinner</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">80dp</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately I need to load another progressspinner for Android-versions < 23. Therefore I added `values-v16` to `values-v22` folders containing a `styles.xml` as follows:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyProgressBarSpinner" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progressspinnerv19</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">80dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">80dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But now when I start the app with android > 23 it also uses the `progressspinnerv19` instead of the one in the main styles.xml.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the values-vXX folders is that what you put there will be used in version XX and **above**. That's why you are seeing that content on android > 23 as well.

What you have in the original styles.xml will instead be used for previous API versions.